# Jagged Array in C - A more efficient method?

Tags: c

I have a function that takes a line from standard input and creates a jagged array, which I will use for a shell I'm building. The idea is that I prompt for input (like a shell) and read the entered line (arguments as well), and then I will call execvp(,) using a fork to execute the command entered from standard input. I have written a function to parse and break up the entered string into a jagged array, and I am looking for a similar function to compare to, or for advice on how to make the function more efficient. Here is the code:

```
int makearg( char *s, char ***args )
{
  int numArgs = 0, i=0, j=0, rows=0, cols=0;

  numArgs = getNumArgs( s );

  // Allocate memory according to number of arguments +1                                                                                                               
  (*args) = (char**)calloc( (numArgs+1), sizeof(char*) );

  while( *(s+i) != '\0' ) {
    // if a space is found, the end of a word is found: copy to ragged array                                                                                           
    if( *(s+i) == ' ' || *(s+i) == '\t' ) {
      // Allocate memory for word                                                                                                                                      
      (*args)[rows] = (char*)malloc( (j+1)*sizeof( char ) );
      // set j-index to the beginning of the word                                                                                                                      
      j = i-j;
      // continue until the end of the word ( i ) is reached                                                                                                           
      while( j < i ) {// copy characters one at a time                                                                                                                 
        (*args)[rows][cols] = *(s+j);
        j++;
        cols++;
      }
      // add a \0 terminator to the word                                                                                                                               
      (*args)[rows][cols] = '\0';
      // reset j - tracks word length                                                                                                                                  
      j = 0;
      // move to next row                                                                                                                                              
      rows++;
      // move to beginning column of that row                                                                                                                          
      cols = 0;
      while( *(s+i+1) == ' ' )
        i++;
    }
    else {
      // if a word end was reached we dont want j incremented                                                                                                          
      j++;
    }
    // continue moving throught the string                                                                                                                             
    i++;
  }
  // When the while loop above finds the \0 at the end of the                                                                                                          
  // string it exits the loop, with one more word to be added.                                                                                                         
  // Add the final word to the ragged array here - same logic.                                                                                                         
  (*args)[rows] = (char*)calloc( (j+1), sizeof( char ) );
  j = i-j;
  while( j < i ) {
    (*args)[rows][cols] = s[j];
    j++;
    cols++;
  }
  (*args)[rows][cols] = '\0';
  rows++;
  cols = 0;
  // here, we add the single element to the final row of                                                                                                               
  // the ragged array. It contains only a \0.                                                                                                                          
  (*args)[rows] = (char*)calloc( 1, sizeof( char ) );
  (*args)[rows][0] = '\0';

  // return the number of arguments.                                                                                                                                   
  return numArgs;
}
```

Comment: man strtok(). With strtok() you could eliminate a lot of your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you leverage `strtok()`, it's much easier to understand and you eliminate `getNumArgs` as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int makearg( char *s, char ***args ) // modifies s in place
{
        int n = 0;
        char *copy = strdup(s);
        for(char *p = strtok(copy, " \t"); p; p = strtok(0, " \t")) {
                n++;
        }
        free(copy);

        char **ap = calloc(n+1, sizeof(char *));

        if(n) {
            ap[0] = strtok(s, " \t");
            for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                ap[i] = strtok(0, " \t");
            }
        }
        *args = ap;
        return n;
}
```